# How to turn the light stronger than your strength in start

Tags: visible-light, photons

Imagine the following scenario:

I have one lamp, and I would like to turn it stronger, like a strength of 2 lamps. 
Can I do it, passing the light (for example) through one crystal or a special glass? If not, has another way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean, "stronger"? You can certainly *focus* it, but you can't increase the total power that's coming out of the lamp (conservation of energy and all that).

Comment: In a way, this is what happens inside lasers. Light passes through the laser medium and stimulates the emission of another photon of the same frequency and direction. Of course, one has to supply energy to the laser medium (pumping) to excite the atoms. It is not possible to do something like this with a completely passive device.

Comment: Also, there are [special crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics) which will absorb two photons and emit one with double the frequency. Thus, energy is conserved. Each photon is more energetic afterwards but there are less.

Comment: I would not want to 'focus' the light. I would like to turn it more stronger without focus the light just in one point.

Comment: What does making it stronger mean? (note, use "stronger" only, "more stronger" is wrong; "even stronger" indicates stronger than "stronger")

Comment: @Jim Thank you by the correction. I mean increase the energy of one lamp has already emitted.

Comment: Energy out = Energy in. To increase the energy out, you have to increase the energy in. To increase the energy of the light after it was emitted, you need either some devices that you already said no to or you need a lot of time and a handy cosmological phenomenon that wouldn't fit in any room of your house (not without killing you at least)

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the power into the light.  How easy that is depends on the light.  If you have a 60W incandescent, the easiest way is to buy a 100W bulb.  Depending on the fixture, the extra heat may be a problem.  If you have a CF or LED bulb, you may again be able to find a higher wattage equivalent.

For a standard incandescent, without replacing the bulb you can increase the supply voltage.  This will increase the visible output more quickly than increasing the power input, as it will raise the temperature and shift output from the infrared to the visible.  It will also burn out the bulb much more quickly and you again may have overheating issues.

No crystal or special glass that I am aware of can provide more light-the conservation of energy gets in the way.

Comment: I guess that you didn't understand what I want, probably is because my very bad English :/. I will try to explain again: I have a 60W lamp, and I want to increase power into this lamp, the photons pass through a "crystal" (or anything) and when the photons leave the crystal, the power of light would be like a 100W lamp, BUT without focus the light in one point.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I saw now you say : `No crystal or special glass that I am aware of can provide more light-the conservation of energy gets in the way.` By the way, thank you by the answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increase the amount of energy that the lamp has already emitted. Not unless you add more energy in some other way.

For typical household lamps the easiest way to double the apparent illuminance of a specific area (a newspaper for example) is to note that some light is being emitted in directions that do not directly illuminate your desired area. You can reflect this light back towards your desired area using a reflector.

Car headlamps use a parabolic reflector (and sometimes a lens) to do this.

A lens won't focus the light into a (useless for reading newspapers) point if you chose the lens and distances such that the light is focussed (if at all) far beyond the newspaper.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Thanks for the correction. I was thinking of night-vision binoculars etc.